# Efficiently pack a list of Longs in Scodec representation

Tags: scala, scodec

I have a case class with a List[Long] attribute that I am converting into a token using the Scodec library.  Right now, it is not efficient (space-wise) because I am using this codec:

listOfN(uint16, int64)

This is using all 64 bits even though my Longs are never more than a few thousand (as of now).  Is there a built-in way in Scodec library to use only as many bits as absolutely needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your long values are non-negative, try using the `vpbcd` codec:

```
listOfN(uint16, vpbcd)
```

This encodes using [variable length packed binary-coded decimal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).